# Facebook Prophet API documenation

Tags: python, facebook-prophet

I'm looking for a API Python documentation for Facebook Prophet

Here there are good examples https://facebook.github.io/prophet/docs

```
future = m.make_future_dataframe(periods=365)
```

or

```
future = m.make_future_dataframe(periods=300, freq='H')
```

But it doesn't explain all possible parameters in `make_future_dataframe`, or the valid values for `freq`.

Any idea where to find the API documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The arguments and API usages are documented as per "October 14, 2022" in this link:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/prophet/prophet.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Here is where it is defined

https://github.com/facebook/prophet/blob/f123a1a7cc6ab51bd21f01e41738d97910a2b2b7/python/fbprophet/forecaster.py#L1548

```
    def make_future_dataframe(self, periods, freq='D', include_history=True):
```

Comment: This is the source code, so I guess it answer my question that there isn't a documented API

Comment: You can easy check source code for methods because sometimes they don't document them. https://facebook.github.io/prophet/docs/quick_start.html